# Source of Jewish hospitality?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Last friday night I came into the synagogue. Hadn't been there since my Bar Mitzvah. As I walked in the entire synagogue turned towards me and greeted me singing a nice song. (something like "dodi dodi" or what not).

I have read of Abraham's hospitality in the bible but didn't expect anything like this. My wife and I were beaming with pride. What is the source of this amazing hospitality?

.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: If you're name was Einu, and they were singing Dayenu... :)

Answer (score 4):

It wasn't a demonstration of hospitality, per se.

"Dodi" is a loose term for a beloved friend. The Friday night service is a time when congregants enjoy singing in shul, and they love it when someone has a sweet voice, as that makes the song sound nicer.

In your case, many of the congregants recall how you sounded at your Bar Mitzvah, and they have missed your beloved voice for so long. In view of the verse:

Song of Songs 2:8:

> ק֣וֹל דּוֹדִ֔י הִנֵּה־זֶ֖ה בָּ֑א

The voice of my beloved (friend) is coming.

the congregants were saying, in a sense, "Wow! a beloved voice that we hadn't heard in a long time, is coming." They were excited to hear your voice and help them join the singing, again. So, they were probably reciting this verse, and, perhaps repeating the word "dodi" as part of their song and enthusiasm to see you.